# Why does Ganache's contract information not accurately display hex values?

Tags: ganache, truffle-migration

Difficulties are as stated above.
Running Truffle v3.5.3, Solidity ^0.8.0, Ganache v2.5.4 local test net.

I have a contract `upcomingRace` which has the following constructor:

```
constructor(string memory _race_id, string[12] memory _horses, uint32 _startTime) payable {
        emit initialized(_race_id, address(this));
        emit firstHorseAndStartTime(_horses[0], _startTime);
        emit lastHorseAndStartTime(_horses[11], _startTime);
        race_id = _race_id;
        startTime = _startTime;
        emit startTimeEvent(startTime);
        string memory _horse;
        for (uint i = 0; i < _horses.length; i++){
            _horse = _horses[i];
            horses[_horse] = true;
        }
    }
```

Declarations of storage variables were omitted for clarity.

I am deploying through the following code:

```
var upcomingRace = artifacts.require("upcomingRace");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(upcomingRace, '54bE7hU0',[...],1621970217);
};
```

When migrating a contract with `truffle migrate --reset`, all the events emitted during instantiation have the expected data.  However, when I look at Contracts > upcomingRace in Ganache, clicking `inspect` gives me the following value,

```
{
    "name": "startTime",
    "type": "uint",
    "value": "60ad4d29"
  }
```

which is the correct hex value for the start time.  But in the GUI, it reads `startTime: uint 61135329` which is obviously not the same as `60ad4d29`.

Why does this occur?  How can I remedy this? I realize the correct data is there underneath but I'd like to be able to check at a glance

Comment: I'd suggest to report the error in ganache's github. It should be a bug.